# Dear IMGUI and DirectX 12 Overlay (DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL)

Tags: c++, directx-12, imgui

I'm trying to make a simple frame counter for DirectX 12 games using Dear IMGUI. I simply want to overlay a small transparent window that displays the sequential order of frames during gameplay. To do so, I hook Present(), so I can get the `SwapChain`, and count the number of times the method is called (frame counting). **THIS IS NOT FOR A CHEAT.** I am not writing cheats for games, I simply want to record frame numbers for analytical purposes.

I have successfully done this for DirectX 11 using the `ShowExampleAppSimpleOverlay()` example provided in here: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/imgui_demo.cpp

Here is an image sample showing the frame counter in a DX 11 game.

[image: An example of the frame counter in DX 11]

I'm now trying to do the same with DirectX 12. Hooking the `Present()` is not an issue.

Using example code provided here: https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/blob/master/examples/example_win32_directx12/main.cpp

I attempt to use the `ShowExampleAppSimpleOverlay()` method again, however in my code on the call to `d3d12CommandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(1, (ID3D12CommandList* const*)&d3d12CommandList);` (to render the overlay) it results in an error saying `(0x887A0001: DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL)`. This is the last line of code in the code sample provided below:

I'm not sure how to proceed. Any thoughts?

Edit: I forgot to mention that I'm also hooking and acquiring the games command que. So `d3d12CommandQueue` is acquired directly from the game. It doesn't return NULL so I'm assuming it is the correct object. I could be wrong though...

For each call to Present() do the following:

```
//iterate frame
Frame_Number = Frame_Number + 1;

//Get Device, using IDXGISwapChain3
ID3D12Device* device;
HRESULT gd = pSwapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D12Device), (void**)&device);
assert(gd == S_OK);

//Get window handle from swapchain for IMGUI
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd;
pSwapChain->GetDesc(&sd);
window = sd.OutputWindow;

//Get backbuffers
buffersCounts = sd.BufferCount;
frameContext = new FrameContext[buffersCounts];

D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC descriptorImGuiRender = {};
descriptorImGuiRender.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV;
descriptorImGuiRender.NumDescriptors = buffersCounts;
descriptorImGuiRender.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;

// Create Descriptor Heap IMGUI render
if (device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&descriptorImGuiRender, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d12DescriptorHeapImGuiRender)) != S_OK)
    return false;

//Create Command Allocator
ID3D12CommandAllocator* allocator;
if (device->CreateCommandAllocator(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, IID_PPV_ARGS(&allocator)) != S_OK)
    return false;

for (size_t i = 0; i < buffersCounts; i++) {
    frameContext[i].commandAllocator = allocator;
}

if (device->CreateCommandList(0, D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_DIRECT, allocator, NULL, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d12CommandList)) != S_OK ||
    d3d12CommandList->Close() != S_OK)
    return false;

//create descriptor heap, describe and create a render target view (RTV) descriptor heap.
D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC descriptorBackBuffers;
descriptorBackBuffers.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV;
descriptorBackBuffers.NumDescriptors = buffersCounts;
descriptorBackBuffers.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_NONE;
descriptorBackBuffers.NodeMask = 1;

if (device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&descriptorBackBuffers, IID_PPV_ARGS(&d3d12DescriptorHeapBackBuffers)) != S_OK)
    return false;
const auto rtvDescriptorSize = device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_RTV);

// Create frame resources.
D3D12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE rtvHandle = d3d12DescriptorHeapBackBuffers->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart();

// Create a RTV for each frame.
for (size_t i = 0; i < buffersCounts; i++) {
    ID3D12Resource* pBackBuffer = nullptr;

    frameContext[i].main_render_target_descriptor = rtvHandle;
    pSwapChain->GetBuffer(i, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pBackBuffer));
    device->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, nullptr, rtvHandle);
    frameContext[i].main_render_target_resource = pBackBuffer;
    rtvHandle.ptr += rtvDescriptorSize;
}

// Setup Platform/Renderer bindings dor IMGUI
ImGui_ImplWin32_Init(window);
ImGui_ImplDX12_Init(device, buffersCounts,
    DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM, d3d12DescriptorHeapImGuiRender,
    d3d12DescriptorHeapImGuiRender->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart(),
    d3d12DescriptorHeapImGuiRender->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
ImGui::GetIO().ImeWindowHandle = window;

// Start the Dear ImGui frame
ImGui_ImplDX12_NewFrame();
ImGui_ImplWin32_NewFrame();
ImGui::NewFrame();

//call imgui menues here
bool bShow = true;
ShowExampleAppSimpleOverlay(&bShow);

// Rendering (imgui)
FrameContext& currentFrameContext = frameContext[pSwapChain->GetCurrentBackBufferIndex()];
currentFrameContext.commandAllocator->Reset();

D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER barrier;
barrier.Type = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_TYPE_TRANSITION;
barrier.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_FLAG_NONE;
barrier.Transition.pResource = currentFrameContext.main_render_target_resource;
barrier.Transition.Subresource = D3D12_RESOURCE_BARRIER_ALL_SUBRESOURCES;
barrier.Transition.StateBefore = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT;
barrier.Transition.StateAfter = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET;

d3d12CommandList->Reset(currentFrameContext.commandAllocator, nullptr);
d3d12CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
d3d12CommandList->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &currentFrameContext.main_render_target_descriptor, FALSE, nullptr);

d3d12CommandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(1, &d3d12DescriptorHeapImGuiRender);

ImGui::Render();
ImGui_ImplDX12_RenderDrawData(ImGui::GetDrawData(), d3d12CommandList);

barrier.Transition.StateBefore = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_RENDER_TARGET;
barrier.Transition.StateAfter = D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_PRESENT;

d3d12CommandList->ResourceBarrier(1, &barrier);
d3d12CommandList->Close();

d3d12CommandQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(1, (ID3D12CommandList* const*)&d3d12CommandList);
```

Answer (score 0):

DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL tells that one command in the list is invalid but not which.
you need to use the d3d12 debug layer for runtime checks at command list creation.
The debug layer also tell you the reason why it is invalid.
see [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/direct3d12/understanding-the-d3d12-debug-layer) for more info.

you can aktivate it with the following code, but it needs to be called before device creation

```
ID3D12Debug* debugInterface;
if (SUCCEEDED(D3D12GetDebugInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&debugInterface)))) {
    debugInterface->EnableDebugLayer();
}
```